# Resampling using Interpolation of ode45 Data in Matlab

Tags: matlab, interpolation, ode, resampling

i tried to use interp1 to solve my ode problem...
i want to interpolate previous data into another equation...
below are the codes...

```
function dxdt = newforced(t,x1,d)
dxdt_1 = x1(2);
dxdt_2 = -100*x1(2)-250000*x1(1)+(25000*(d^3)); %data should be interpolated at d
dxdt = [dxdt_1;dxdt_2];

tspan=[0:0.1:100];
d=x(:,1);   %x is data sampling from previous ode
initial_x1=0;
initial_dxdt=0;
f=interp1(t,d,x);
[t,x1]=ode45(@newforced,tspan,[initial_x1 initial_dxdt]);
figure
plot(t,x,':')
figure
plot(d,f)
```

**Issue:** I have 2 variables (d and x(:,1)) and I want to resample one to match the length of the other.

codes above is not working as many error pops up...
can anybody please correct me
thanks

Comment: Are you simply trying to resample the data to fit a certain length?

Comment: yup
resample data but from another ode

Comment: So if I understood you correctly, you have 2 variables and you want to resample one to match the length of the other? If so, which two variables are in question?

Comment: the two variables are d and x(:,1) ....

Comment: Please kindly verify my solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a toy example. Just replace `x` and `y` with `d` and `x(:,1)`.

```
% Example Data
x = 0:9;
y = 1:0.1:10;

% Check if y is longer
if length(x) < length(y)
    x = interp1( x, linspace( 1, length(x), length(y) ) );   % Resample x
else
    y = interp1( y, linspace( 1, length(y), length(x) ) );   % Resample y
end
```

So `linespace` will generate indicies between 1 and length(x) with length(y) number of divisions.

Essentially `interp1` will resample the variable to the length of the other one. The if statement will check which one needs resampling.

Comment: @MohamadAmirul If this worked for you, can you kindly accept it as the answer using the checkmark?